# three state toggle button for each row in table

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

three state toggle button whose functionality is different in each row in table.and store their value in array foam.like in first row i select toggle button on and in next row i will select off. all these value store in array foam

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 1;
$(".add-row").click(function(){
var table = document.getElementById("choose-address-table");
var row   = table.insertRow(-1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var val = ++i;
cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='key_performance[]'                   id='key_performance' >";
cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='target[]' id='target'>";
cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='actual[]' id='actual'>";
cell4.innerHTML = '<div id="rates"><input type="radio" id="r1"  name="rate'+(val)+'" value="1"><input type="radio" id="r2" name="rate'+ (val)+'" value="0"><input type="radio" id="r3" name="rate'+(val)+'" value="2" checked="checked"></div>'
 });
 </script>
 <script>
 var data4 = new Array(); 
 $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function()
 {
 var ttt = $(this).val();
 data4.push(ttt);
 });
```